# Getting TypeError: next is not a function at Object.viteServeStaticMiddleware [as handle] when inserting iframe in sveltekit

Tags: iframe, plotly, vite, sveltekit

As the title says, when i try to insert an iframe with the src attribute being the absolute filepath, i get the error in a black box:

```
<div class="output_html rendered_html output_subarea ">
     <iframe scrolling="no" width="100%" height="545px" src="src/lib/model/model_iframe_figures/figure_4.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure that it can find the iframe files but i'm not sure what's causing the errors. I've searched online and havent found similar issues that has to do with inserting iframes.

The iframe i'm trying to insert is a .html file that has a plotly graph, not sure if that's the issue.